# Ctrl+Ins keybinding won't work in Vim, does in gVim?

Tags: gvim

I have the following in my `.vimrc` (I don't recall where I found the original):

```
" Cut, Copy, Paste
vnoremap <S-Del>        "+x
vnoremap <C-Insert>     "+y
```

If I use Shift+Cursor keys to select some text and then press Ctrl+Ins to copy that text to the X11 clipboard, it works fine in gVim, but not in Vim.

Further investigation (using `noremap <Leader>y "+y`) suggests that there's nothing wrong with the clipboard support, but rather something wrong with the keybinding.

I confirmed this by:

```
noremap <Leader>p :echo 'hello'<CR>
noremap <C-Insert> :echo 'hello'<CR>
```

The former works; the latter does nothing.

*Linux Mint 18.3, Cinnamon, Gnome Terminal*

Comment: Not a duplicate: It appears to be the Ctrl+Ins that's not working in Vim, rather than the `"+y`.

Comment: I've edited my question to be about the keybinding, rather than the clipboard.

Comment: @Rich, yeah, that looks like the problem. Sigh. I was kinda enjoying using vim in a terminal window, but it's gonna be hard to retrain my CUA-fingers.

Comment: It's terminal related issue. <C-Insert> catched by your terminal. Actually any <Ctrl> and <Alt> mappings.